# How to bump multiple commit message with semantic versioning prefixes

Tags: github-actions

I have 3 commits in a pull request that I want to merge to my master branch,1 each for chore, fix and feat. I always want it to increase the minor version regardless of the commit order. Below is my changelog and release tag action. How can I make sure that when my pull request is merge to master its able to bump the version accordingly. Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance

```
on:
  push:
   branches:
     - master

jobs:
  release:
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest

   steps:
    - name: checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: conventional changelog action
      id: changelog
      uses: TriPSs/conventional-changelog-action@latest
      with:
        github-token: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"

    - name: create release
      uses: softprops/action-gh-release@v1
      if: ${{steps.changelog.outputs.skipped == 'false'}}
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      with:
          tag_name: ${{ steps.changelog.outputs.tag }}
          name: ${{ steps.changelog.outputs.tag }}
          body: ${{steps.changelog.outputs.clean_changelog}}
          draft: false
          prerelease: false
```